# scss mixin not compiling correctly

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to size some text relative to the viewport, and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container).

I'm now experimenting with the idea of using something akin to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935472/680920)

```
font-size: calc(3vw + 3vh);
```

So I came up with this scss

```
/* Font sizing based on size of the viewport */
@mixin vp-font-size($multiplier: 1) {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * $multiplier);
}
.vp-font-size {
  p {
    @include vp-font-size(.8);
  }
  .h6 {
    @include vp-font-size(.9);
  }
  .h5 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.0);
  }
  .h4 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.1);
  }
  .h3 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.2);
  }
  .h2 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.3);
  }
  .h1 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.4);
  }
}
```

However, it's compiling to this

```
.vp-font-size p {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * $multiplier); }

.vp-font-size .h6 {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * $multiplier); }

.vp-font-size .h5 {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * $multiplier); }

.vp-font-size .h4 {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * $multiplier); }

.vp-font-size .h3 {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * $multiplier); }

.vp-font-size .h2 {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * $multiplier); }

.vp-font-size .h1 {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * $multiplier); }
```

When I put something like `font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * 1.1)`, my browser can understand it. So is there something wrong with the scss parser I'm using?

I was reading the [scss documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins-arguments) and it seems valid. I'm using [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off. On the line with `calc`, `$multiplier` should be `#{$multiplier}`

`@mixin vp-font-size($multiplier: 1) {
  font-size: calc((1vw + 1vh) * #{$multiplier});
}
.vp-font-size {
  p {
    @include vp-font-size(.8);
  }
  .h6 {
    @include vp-font-size(.9);
  }
  .h5 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.0);
  }
  .h4 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.1);
  }
  .h3 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.2);
  }
  .h2 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.3);
  }
  .h1 {
    @include vp-font-size(1.4);
  }
}`

Edit:

Here is a link to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBPPBo) with the SCSS. To view the compiled code, click the carrot in the top right of the CSS panel and "View compiled CSS".

Comment: Thanks dude, it's compiling! Can you share a link to that syntax, and perhaps an explanation thereof?

Comment: Hey man, IDK if I can explain it much more than I did at the start of the answer. I just looked and noticed that when you were trying to use the `$multiplier` argument in the body of the mixin, that you had forgotten to wrap it in `#{   }`.

Comment: Hmm, it's interesting because I don't see that being used in the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins-arguments).

Comment: I found it, it's called [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)